# Does a predefined mediator exist for REST-to-SOAP or SOAP-to-REST mediation?

Tags: java, rest, soap, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-integration-studio

I have a requirement where I'll receive SOAP calls and need to mediate them to REST calls, and vice versa, to invoke some services using WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0.

Could you please confirm if WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0 includes built-in functionality to address this requirement, or if I need to develop it from scratch?

Any assistance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards.